# Autocomplete json in textbox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, textbox

Below is my json output:

```
{["0001000","0002000","0001200","00003000","990000","78888","89234","2345","2345"]}
```

How can i implement autosuggest in a text box field using the above json array?

Comment: If you don't want to go with Jquery UI, you can use a jquery plugin for autocomplete. Here is a [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19157288/386579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI, the [jQuery documentation on autocomplete is straightforward](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). Put your array as the `source:` and it should work automatically.

Comment: If my result returns -->aaData:"0001000","0002000","0001200","00003000","990000","78888","89234","2345","2345"],where i need to delete the "aaData"..In my action class ,the jsonresponse.put(aaData,data),where the Value are in "data".

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, You seriously need to spend some time for googling and  looking into the documentations.

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) library already provides this feature.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

You need to include 2 scripts in your HTML page

1) jQuery library

2) jQuery UI library

**HTML**

```
<input id="tags">​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    var availableTags=["0001000","0002000","0001200","00003000","990000","78888","89234","2345","2345"];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
    });

});
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/j9XBd/3/

Comment: How to set the URL for the Json , My result returns as --> aaData:"0001000","0002000","0001200","00003000","990000","78888","89234","2345","2345"] , when i hard code the values it works ,but when i set the URL it does't work , would you please place a code for reference.

Comment: @PrashanthReddy: Check this http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote. You need to return proper JSON from your server page. User www.jsonlint.com to validate whether your JSON is correct form or not.

Comment: How to set the values in the action through the Jsonresponse in an array . thanks

Comment: @PrashanthReddy: IMHO, The chances of getting an answer when you ask a new question in the comments is very low.l So i encourage you to ask a new question with relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Just use:

`["0001000","0002000","0001200","00003000","990000","78888","89234","2345","2345"];`

without `{}` like following:

```
var json  = ["0001000","0002000","0001200","00003000","990000","78888","89234","2345","2345"];

$('input:text').autocomplete(json, {

});
```

or you can automatically set the source

```
$(input:text).autocomplate({
   souce: SOURCE_TO_YOUR_STORE
});
```