# Autocomplete Without jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery in my project and I need to implement autocomplete, but I'd like to avoid including jQuery UI widget, and hopefully use some specific external plugin.
Could you please provide some examples/link?
I have to query a remote JSON source that returns key-value couples.

Comment: You can always include [only the parts of jQueryUI you need](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Comment: Was not happy with other solutions,  so wrote my own. https://gist.github.com/d3ep4k/1816f47fb9949d565bde11ee9b18cc61

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery plugin](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)

And here is the [full documentation](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

**Code**

**SCRIPT**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.24/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script>
   a1 = $('#query').autocomplete({
         width: 448,
         delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
         lookup: 'Andorra,Azerbaijan,Bahamas,Bahrain,Benin,Bhutan,Bolivia,Bosnia Herzegovina,Botswana,Brazil,Brunei,Bulgaria,Burkina, Burundi,Cambodia,Cameroon,Canada,Cape Verde,Central African Rep,Chile,China,Colombia,Comoros,Congo,Congo {Democratic Rep},Costa Rica,Croatia,Cuba,Cyprus,Czech Republic,Denmark,Djibouti,East Timor,Ecuador,Egypt,El Salvador,Equatorial Guinea,Eritrea,Fiji,France,Georgia,Germany,Ghana,Greece,Grenada,Guatemala,Guinea,Guinea-Bissau,Guyana,Haiti,Honduras,Hungary,India,Iraq,Ireland {Republic},Ivory Coast,Jamaica,Japan,Kazakhstan,Kiribati,Korea North,'.split(',')
      }); 
    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-field {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.73684em;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 37px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions strong {
    color: #3399FF;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.autocomplete-selected{
  background:#F0F0F0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" id="query" class="text-field valid" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search here">
```

I created a demo of `autocomplete` here is the link [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/kisosesako/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 24):

You can use HTML5 'list' attribute in your input textbox and provide it a custom list of values by using datalist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--your stuff-->
</head>
<body>
<!--your stuff-->
<input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList"/><!--your input textbox-->
<datalist id="languageList">
<option value="HTML" />
<option value="CSS" />
<option value="JavaScript" />
<option value="SQL" />
<option value="PHP" />
<option value="jQuery" />
<option value="Bootstrap" />
<option value="Angular" />
<option value="ASP.NET" />
<option value="XML" />
</datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

If you didn't get it, Read more at http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/09/create-auto-complete-dropdown-using.html

**There's a video as well for it**  [Auto-Complete Without JQuery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wd4RI9mm8Hk)

Answer (score 7):

Here is one little autocomplete plugin written by me, please try: https://github.com/Fischer-L/autoComplt

Because I am not using jQuery and don't want to include some big libs just for one feature, I write for myself.

This plugin doesn't depend on other libs and doesn't have to include other CSS, so just including one JS script is enough.

P.S If you use it and find some thing which needs to be improved, please tell me :)

Comment: Don't suppose you planned to implement Ajax, you could just save me from jquery :)

Comment: @Fischer Yes! Please enhance with the ability to source the list from an AJAX call. What you've done is awesome because it doesn't look like it modifies the DOM around the input. I've beehttp://stackoverflow.com/users/1123047/fischern trying to find something like this to use in different UI frameworks without breaking the layout. I do also need to trigger a server side search, great start though!

Comment: @AlecTeal If you are still interested in this, the control does actually support AJAX https://gist.github.com/rupe120/bc520aaac48608b0c3d825d13dda6deb

Answer (score 2):

I've started writing an auto complete / mentioning plugin in plain Javascript. I't not completed yet, but it could be a good start point.

[github](https://github.com/alihaghighatkhah/highlighterJS)

Comment: It's working. beside the coding style, what's the problem with it?

Comment: yes. working but lack multiple instantiating capability. easy to implement but I don't have enough time to change it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to include JQuery or any other third party library.

`IP_autoComplete` function will automatically concatinate field value to URL (1st parameter). For example textbox has value `neeraj` then `arrjson.php?Name=neeraj` will be triggered.

You can use IP_autocomplete function for static value as well. Just add # sign once at starting in your string (comma sepreated). E.g: "#val1,val2,val3"

arrjson.php should return json encoded string.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.iperfect.net/js/IP_generalLib.js">
```

Body

```
<input type="text" name="testautocomplete" id="testautocomplete" onkeypress="IP_autoComplete('arrjson.php?Name=',this.id,event)">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neeraj3728/j9vjw763/)

Or simply you can give static:

```
<input type="text" name="testneeraj" id="testneeraj" onkeyup="IP_autoComplete('#sachin bhalake,ishwar agam,mohsin khan,neeraj dhekale,sheetal dhekale,ajay bhalake',this.id,event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

This the best multi category/feature Autocomplete plugin I have ever seen, it contains many features and gives you full control over 40 parameters to customize it as you wish. It is so dynamic and provides multi languages inputs with auto detection for RTL or LTR languages.

It doesn't use the JQuery and the code has very light size and so clean.

**The demo page:** http://www.muwakaba.com/plugins/autocomplete

You can use it with different configurations on the demo page and see all the parameters and the features.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/place-search-js/v1.0.0/place-search.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/place-search-js/v1.0.0/place-search.css"/>
```

Here is input :

```
<input type="search" id="place-search-input" placeholder="Start Searching..."/>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ps;
window.onload = function () {
    ps = placeSearch({
        key: 'lYrP4vF3Uk5zgTiGGuEzQGwGIVDGuy24',
        container: document.querySelector('#place-search-input'),
        useDeviceLocation: false,
        collection: [
            'poi',
            'airport',
            'address',
            'adminArea',
        ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score -10):

Try this, this will be help you

HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript", "AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure",
      "COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell","Java",
      "JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

Fiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/fJwAs/)

Comment: you should add code also. else it is pointless if link goes dead.

Comment: @Subhash OP doensn't want to use `jquery ui` and you are using `jquery ui autocomplete widget`

Comment: In your answer ui also used @RohanKumar